# What is the area bounded by the curve?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, area

I need to determine the area between this curve
$y=sinx+cosx$ and this curve $y=|cosx-sinx|$ from x=[0,pi/2]

I am solving this by converting in $(2)^1/2sin(x+Pi/4)$ form.and my answer is coming out to be 2 which is wrong.

Can someone help me find the solution?

Comment: From ?   to ?  you want to find area ?

Comment: :see this ,to get hint $$\\$$https://www.desmos.com/calculator/d2rcy3xu3j

Comment: you will Need the intersection Points of both curves

Answer (score 0):

One first needs to find the points of intersection of the two curves.  However, I will assume that you know this already as this is quite elementary.

Usually, when integrating with the modulus function, you need to split the integral and solve it separately for parts where the function is positive and negative.  In this case, you need to integrate the difference between the functions from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and from $\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, because that is when $cos(x)-sin(x)$ is positive and negative respectively.  Thus, solving the following integrals and adding them will give you the area bound by the two. However, in this case, since you know that the area is the same from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and from $\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$, you only need to evaluate the area on one side and then multiply it by 2.

$$2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} sin(x)+cos(x)-(cos(x)-sin(x))dx = 4\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} sin(x) dx$$